# como reemplazar caracteres especiales de java Ã©

Tags: java, string, caracteres

tengo un string con unos caracteres que reemplazan las vocales con acentos y quiero reemplazarlas pero no me lo permite. Adjunto el código

```
public String ReemplazarCaracteres() {
    String original = new String("AmÃ©rica");  //(América)
    String nuevo = original.replace('Ã©', 'e');   //reemplazo

    return nuevo;
}
```

Comment: Hola a todos, se me corto la primera parte de la pregunta, era para preguntar si podian ayudarme o sugerirme alguna libreria o metodo para poder hacer este tipo de reemplazos. Gracias, saludos

Comment: hola, solo retorna nuevo sin las " " seria return nuevo;

Comment: Hola @victorleroz  debes definir los caracteres a reemplazar dentro de comilla doble, de esta forma:  "Ã©" , así podrás reemplazar estos caracteres sin problema, agregué respuesta,  saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**La forma correcta para reemplazar los caracteres `Ã©` es usar como contenedor la doble comilla**, ya que si usas comilla sencilla `'Ã©'` como contenedor de estos caracteres, no podrás realizar el reemplazo.

Realiza el siguiente cambio en tu función:

```
  public static String ReemplazarCaracteres() {
    String original = new String("AmÃ©rica");  //(América)
    //String nuevo = original.replace('Ã©', 'e');   //reemplazo incorrecto!
    String nuevo = original.replace("Ã©", "e");   //reemplazo correcto.
    return nuevo;
  }
```

de esta forma al llamar el método anterior, obtendrías como salida:

```
America
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que estas retornando un string "nuevo" y no la variable `nuevo`

Por lo que tu codigo tendria que ser de esta manera:

```
public String ReemplazarCaracteres() {
    String original = new String("AmÃ©rica");  //(América)
    String nuevo = original.replace('Ã©', 'e');   //reemplazo

    return nuevo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren unas dudas a tu pregunta, necesitas cambiar las letras por que el IDE que usas para programar, te cambia  los signos? o al mostrar tu pagina se muestran estos caracteres especiales?

lo comento porque java como cualquier otro lenguaje son capaces de manejar estos caracteres especiales, solo debes saber como configurar tu IDE.

en el caso de eclipse.

tienen que ir  las siguientes opciones windows-->preferences-->general--> workspace  en este menu debes modificar el text file encoding

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en caso caso que sea en html puedes usar el siguiente tag

por ultimo si efectivamente si tu programa necesita, transformar estos valores lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera

public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print(ReemplazarCaracteres());
    }

```
public static String ReemplazarCaracteres() {
        String original = new String("AmÃ©ricÃ@Ã©");  //(América)
        return original.replaceAll("Ã©", "é").replaceAll("Ã@", "á");   //reemplazo
}
```

en este punto te recomiendo usar replaceAll, ya que puede venir mas de una palabra con caracteres especiales, ademas lo puedes usar las veces que sea necesario, por si necesitas reemplazar otros caracteres (puse como ejemplo Ã@ = 'a.

ademas te recomiendo unos variables si no son necesarias, ya hacen uso de memoria, en este caso puede retornar de inmediato el valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema de fondo que yo veo no es el que tu cadena tenga caracteres en una codificación que no es la de donde lo corres. Por ello algunas de las soluciones que te den podrían no funcionar, para evitar que tus cadenas tengan caracteres especiales dependientes de una codificación (o como casos extremos kanjies o caracteres arábigos, griegos, katakana, hiragana u otros) puedes usar la herramienta `native2ascii` que viene con tu JDK.

Se usa de la siguiente forma:

```
native2ascii -encoding [nombre de codificación] [archivo orígen] [archivo salida]
```

De esa manera aunque le metas los caracteres más raros te generará su equivalente en unicode y se verá igual sin importar la codificación nativa que tenga tu fichero.

Si tienes duda de como funciona, es prácticamente lo mismo que hace este código:

```
public static String encode(String input) {
    return Stream.of(input.split("")).map(
            (character) ->
                    String.format("\\u%04x", character.codePointAt(0))
    ).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

En tu caso tras la conversión podrías usar:

```
String original = new String("Am\u00e9rica");
System.out.println(original);
```

> América